# How to enclose a quoted variable in quotes

Tags: shell, quoting, arguments

I want to call: `./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -r 320x240" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www"` from a C program, running `system()`.

The problem is that I have to enclose shell command in quotes, which arleady exist. How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't this more of a C question than a Unix one?

Comment: Also, don't use `system()` for anything beyond a toy project.  Using `fork()` and `exec()` gives you much more control and has many fewer security implications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the escape character `\` like this:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i \"./input_uvc.so -r 320x240\" -o \"./output_http.so -w ./www\"
```